# Python- reading a file line by line and processing

Tags: python

I want to read a input file line and line and if the line has some characters
i want to skip that line and read next line. Apart from skipped lines rest all lines need to be written to an ouput file. created the below code with a function but lines are not written in the output file ,can someone let me know the error/correction.

```
  import os
  import time 
  timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
  inputfile_str='input.txt'
  outputfile_str='output.txt'
  directory = os.path.normpath("C:/Users/Desktop/Python/Input")

  FILE_NAME=inputfile_str
  file_identifier = 'input.txt'
  def writeroutine(line):
      print(line)
      for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
          if file==outputfile_str:
         outputfile.write(line)


for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
   for file in files:
      outputfile = open("Output.txt",'w')
       if file==inputfile_str:
        f=open(os.path.join(subdir,file),'r')
        for line in f:
            if line[0:12] == "AAAAAAAAAAAA" or line[20:29] == "##### ##:":
                continue
            else:
                writeroutine(line)
```

Comment: "lines are not written in the output file" meaning none of the lines are being written at all? Also, can you please format your code correctly?

Comment: The spacing in your code looks strange, can you ensure the code you've pasted here has the same spacing as the code in your editor?

Comment: Why are you walking the input directory before you write to the output file? I don't think you need that loop.

Comment: I can see several problems here, the output file will be created in whatever dir you execute the code and not in "C:/Users/Desktop/Python/Input", also why do you walk the directory and check if the file exist at every write? Same for the input. Also you 'open' the output file fore every input file

Answer (score 0):

your outputfile variable shoud be declared in global scope. you have declared in within for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you are getting the way to check if a file exist in python wrong:

```
import os

inputfile_str = 'input.txt'
outputfile_str = 'output.txt'
directory = os.path.normpath("C:/Users/Desktop/Python/Input")

out_file = open( os.path.join(directory ,outputfile_str ), "w")
with open( os.path.join(directory ,inputfile_str ), "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0:12] == "AAAAAAAAAAAA" or line[20:29] == "##### ##:":
            continue
        else:
            out_file.write( line)

out_file.close()
```

If you want to catch an exception if the file doesn't exist you could put everything( bad practice) or just the file open line inside a try statement:

```
try:
    code_with_possible:exception
except Exception as r:
    handle_exception
```

For example

```
try:
    out_file = open( os.path.join(directory ,outputfile_str ), "w")
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print( e)
    ...more_exception_handling
```

Comment: Comment for the suggested edit @Aaron_ab:
Removing the outfile from the first piece of code would not make it work by simply copypasting, what i explain after is an addition on how to catch exception and not something meant to replace the original piece. Regarding the condition in the cycle, while I agree it might be more effective to negate the condition since the continue is at the start of the loop, I think the use of continue makes the code easier to read/understand at a quick glance for the intent of skipping a line

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make it *that* complicated.

```
bad_guys = ["AAAAAAAAAAAA", "##### ##:"]
with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile:
    with open('output.txt', 'a') as outfile: 
        for line in infile: 
            if (bad_guys[0] in line) or (bad_guys[1] in line):
                continue
            else: 
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: No need to close the file when you are using the with ... as ...: that is what using with is for. Checking only for the 'in line' might not be the right behavior as intended in the question. Also this opens an input/output file in the current directory and not in a specified one

Comment: @Crivella the asker is able to locate input and output files. The answers clarifies the main issue of the asker: not being able to write to output file. Moreover, the answer keeps concepts simple and more easily integrable in the asker workflow. Please also consider to edit your comment because there is no more close().

Comment: I think the time limit to edit comments is 5 minutes, anyway i was just trying to infer what the asker aim was given the starting piece of code. I agree that your answer gives can be easily adapted by the asker to his needs, but given the piece of code he is using to open/check for a file i thought he might not be very familiar with python hence the need try and integrate all possible scenarios